# Why does App state resets when using Webpack HMR plugin with Redux- DevTools?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, webpack-hmr, redux-devtools

**I'm using webpack Hot Module Replacement(HMR) Plugin with Redux Devtools Chrome extension. However whenever the HMR runs, the Redux local app state resets to all the initial values. My webconfig is the following:**

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import path from 'path'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'

const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event

const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === 'production'
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
}

const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: PATHS.app + '/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
})

const productionPlugin2 = new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compressor: {
    warnings: false
  }
})

const base = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    PATHS.app
  ],
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'}
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('./app')
  }
}

const developmentConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: PATHS.build,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    progress: true
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig, new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
}

const productionConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig, productionPlugin, productionPlugin2]
}

export default Object.assign({}, base, isProduction === true ? productionConfig : developmentConfig)
```

**And here is what my main App index.js looks like:**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import getRoutes from './config/routes'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { authUser, unauthUser, fetchingUserSuccess } from 'redux/modules/users'
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { initAuth, formatUserInfo } from 'helpers/auth'
import * as reducers from 'redux/modules'

let reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
// const store = createStore(
//   reducer,
//   compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
//    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f))

function configureStore () {
  const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
   window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f))

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('redux/modules', () => {
      store.replaceReducer(require('redux/modules').default)
    })
  }
  return store
}

const store = configureStore()

export function checkAuth (nextState, replace) {
  // debugger
  // console.log('isAuthed from Main container mount')
  // const isAuthed = checkIfAuthed(store)
  const isAuthed = store.getState().users.isAuthed
  // const isAuthed = store.getState().isAuthed
  console.log('isAuthed from checkAuth method', isAuthed)
  const nextPathName = nextState.location.pathname
  console.log('nextPathName', nextPathName)
  // debugger
  if ((isAuthed !== true) && (nextPathName !== 'auth')) {
      // debugger
    console.log('replaced path to auth')
    replace('auth')
  } else if ((nextPathName === '/' || nextPathName === 'auth') && (isAuthed === true)) {
      // debugger
    console.log('replaced path to feed')
    replace('feed')
  }
}

initAuth()
.then((user) => {
  if (user !== null) {
    console.log('intial user', user.displayName)
    store.dispatch(authUser(user.uid))
    const userInfo = formatUserInfo(user.displayName, user.photoURL, user.uid)
    store.dispatch(fetchingUserSuccess(user.uid, userInfo))
  } else {
    console.log('intial user is :', user)
    store.dispatch(unauthUser())
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
    {getRoutes(checkAuth)}
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('ERROR', error)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I cannot replicate the issue (a jsfiddle would be welcome), updating the store after the replacement should help:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('redux/modules', () => {
  store.replaceReducer(require('redux/modules').default)
  if (window.devToolsExtension) window.devToolsExtension.updateStore(store)
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) persisted the app state through page refreshed action and tab or browser closing.

Answer (score -1):

> Remove this method inside your App index.js

```
if (module.hot) {
module.hot.accept('redux/modules', () => {
  store.replaceReducer(require('redux/modules').default)
})}
```

Comment: I just recently added this snippet of code because I was told it will make it work. It doesnt with or without this snippet you asked me to remove. if you notice right above the configureStore function I have a commented code. I also have ran it by commenting the configureStore function and uncomment the code above it in which i just create a const store using createStore